# How to get full statistics on firebase notification using message_id?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When sending a message from the Java FCM SDK, I get a `message_id` from Firebase. It is unclear what to do with it next.
At the same time, I would like to have statistics on each notification and hope to use this message_id to get all the details

message_id from firebase response = projects/uno-c0edf/messages/4368314790085249035

I was surfing the Internet and found out about BigQuery and exporting firebase cloud messaging records to it. Although this is also not all clear.

Are there any other ways to pull firebase message data by `message_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging does not maintain persistent data for the individual messages it sends. At the volume of messages it sends, that would be untenable.

The best you can get within the FCM API is [aggregated delivery data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#aggregated_delivery_data_via_the_data_api), which shows the overall delivery data - but can't be used to find details on delivery of individual messages.

As you've found, you can [export delivery data to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#bigquery-data-export), which gives you the most details on the delivery of each individual message. If something specific is not clear about that documentation, I recommend asking a specific question about it - showing what you have done already based on the documentation and trying to apply that to your needs.